# How can I open a .mdb with a password in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice, microsoft-access, openoffice-base, mdb

I'm trying to open a .mdb with a password in OpenOffice Base. I can connect to the .mdb, but I cannot specify a password (forums say this method doesn't support passwords). Is there a way I can open this file using Base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic is opened since 2009 and nobody has answered well. 
With OpenOffice 4.0.1 it is simple. 
Everybody is trying open directly the access database using the Connect to an existing database and selecting Microsoft access connexion, and this option fails in case the database is protected by password. 
In case you are finding this problem try this one:

1. Connect to an existing database
2. Select ODBC
3. Click on explore and select the data source name is pointing to your databes. In case you have not created the data source name we are going to create it now.
4. Click on Manage or Create (it depends of your language).
5. Click on Add.
6. Select Microsoft Access driver (*.mdb)
7. write a name for the new data source name.
8. click on Select in the data base and select your database.
9. Once you have selected the database and before to accept you must click on Advanced.
10. write here the password and accept everything
11. Select the data source name created
12. accept everything and finish

I have followed all these steps and it worked. 
Hope can help you too.

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_to_Microsoft_Access